# Django constantly re-creates AlterField migration for m2m field

Tags: django, django-models, manytomanyfield

I have a very annoying situation with my model

I renamed a Model used as ManyToMany table

```py
# The business models contains this field
admins = models.ManyToManyField("users.User", through=BusinessMember)
    
# this is the many to many model used in in Business
class BusinessMember(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        "users.User", related_name="memberships", null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    business = models.ForeignKey(
        "business.Business", related_name="members", null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    class Meta:
        db_table = "myproject__business_member"
```

This model once was called "BusinessUser" and I had to rename it. I created the following migrations to rename the Model

```py
# Rename and alter model table 0011_rename_business_user_model.py
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ("business", "0010_add_business_field"),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RenameModel("businessuser", "businessmember"),
        migrations.AlterModelTable(
            name="businessmember",
            table="myproject__business_member",
        ),
    ]
    

# Another migration to update the sequence

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ("business", "0011_rename_business_user_model"),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunSQL(
            "alter sequence myproject_business_user_id_seq rename to myproject__business_member_id_seq;"
        ),
    ]
```

After this change, the makemigrations constantly create a migration with this AlterField

```py
migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='business',
        name='admins',
        field=models.ManyToManyField(through='business.BusinessMember', to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
    ),
```

It doesn't matter how many times I migrated this `AlterField`, Django creates another migration every time.

Do you have any idea what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I am also running into a similar problem when trying to add a ManyToMany field on a model to a custom User model. It keeps making the same AlterField migration. The only solution I've found so far is to put the ManyToMany field directly on the User model as the source and the other model as the target, but this does not seem ideal. This feels like a Django bug.

Comment: I was able to reproduce this when trying to add a ManyToMany field on a model back to a Custom User (i.e. you extended AbstractUser). This is definitely a django bug.

Comment: I've reproduced this when using a custom user (i.e. extending AbstractUser) and here is the bug report https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/33515

Comment: This issue is fixed in Django 4.0. unfortunately, I've the same issue in 1.11